# .env file is not working in backend (express JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I added the database name and password in .env file, but when I called the .env in index.js (express) it didn't work.

const uri = `mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB}:${process.env.PASSWORD}@cluster0.vliyf.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;

Comment: Did you import and configure dotenv?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use values from a `.env` file in your script, you need to import and configure the [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package:

```js
require('dotenv').config()
```

(don't forget to install it first: `npm install dotenv` )
You don't show any code but that could be the problem